# python -c as a docker entrypoint

Tags: python, docker

I am trying to test a docker container in my CI/CD pipeline by running a small piece of python code. What I was hoping would work is something like this:

```
docker run --entrypoint "python3 -c" image-name "import os;..."
```

However I get error, even if I replace `python3` with `python`

```
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec: "python3 -c": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown.
```

Right now I create a script during runtime and mount it using volume

```
docker run --entrypoint "python3" -v /tmp/testing/script.py:/testscript.py image-name script.py
```

Is there any way how to make `python3 -c` work in similar manner to my current solution? Or how would you perform a simple test which involves running a container and running some simple python code inside?
EDIT: I have `/bin/bash` entrypoint running a `sh` script in my dockerfile, I am trying to override this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After seeing @jabsson's answer I was able to come up with this

```
docker run --entrypoint "python" image-name -c "print('hello')"
```

which does exactly what I needed. Thank you for the idea

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the whole command at the end, would the following work for you?

```
docker run \
python:alpine \
python -c "import time; print('sleeping for 3 secs'); time.sleep(3); print('done sleeping')"
```

Comment: I edited my answer to be more specific. I have already setup an entrypoint during build as /bin/bash and a shell script to be executed. I would like to override this, because the shell scriipt is too long and for the sake of testing I just need a small python part to be run.

Comment: Your Dockerfile doesn't need an `ENTRYPOINT`.  If you're at all considering overriding the command like you show here, don't set an `ENTRYPOINT` at all and put the entire command in `CMD`.